# How could Basilisk Eyes affect the Plastic Camera of Colin Creevy?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

The Basilisk in Book 2 reminds me much of Greek mythology Medusa who could kill anyone who sees her with his/her naked eyes. 
It was not that some sort of rays or extreme heat or light emits from the eyes (Medusa or Basilisk) - Its just that they look so fearsome and horrified that the person who sees them die of the mere shock.

Now, a person with feelings of fear and foreboding, understandably could die of shock on seeing a real life 50 foot or so giant snake with huge fangs but this however doesn't give any explanation on how the plastic camera of Colin Creevy was damaged and the film inside was burnt when Colin saw the Basilisk through it.

Any theory?

Comment: Any fool proof way to find out if the question has been asked before. While typing the question, I didn't get any info (the list of questions that popup in relevance to the keywords being entered) about the similar question and presumed that this is a fresh question. Just wondering if there is way to make sure with which I can avoid asking duplicate questions.

Comment: If you really want to make sure, you could ask one of the subject matter experts in chat. Of course, there is nothing wrong with having one's question closed as duplicate.